# IIS keep some urls when changing domain

Tags: iis

I will be changing a www server to be ww2. Making a new server the www server. The new server has IIS 8.5 running, with https, ASP.Net/MVC. The old server does not have https.
I have some urls that users may have bookmarked to the old www. I would like those urls to still work (doesn't matter if the browser displays ww2). I have made sure those urls are unique and don't conflict with any resource/path on the new server. Some urls are a resource like .html others are any in a path.  Do I put all of those urls in as redirects in IIS on my new server? Are redirects the best of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the URL_REWRITE Extension.

You can download it here: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Then apply the rewrite rules at the server level not the application level. This will allow you to easily control the the flow of any your old URLs to your new location.

Depending on how many you have theirs a few different ways you can do it with URL_Rewrite.

To get you started here's a bunch of tutorials on how to use it: https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module

After you play with it and if have any specific questions, just ask on stackoverflow and tag the question with `URL-REWRITE-MODULE`